# Occasional Failure of a HTML Form

Tags: html, forms

I have what I think is a pretty simple form for filling in a couple of dates and sending the user to another page. Unfortunately I find that occasionally the data is not passed to the new page, although the user does get to the page.

The code of my form is

```
<form action="/book/book1.php" method="post" target="_blank" id="bookboxform" name="bookboxform">
<input name="hid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $hid ?>">
<!-- This next line added to provide an alternative identification of the hotel -->
<input name="hotelname" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row_hotel['hotel'] ?>">
<input type="text" name="ArrivalDate" id="ArrivalDate" value="" placeholder="Loading.... please wait" readonly>
<input type="text" name="DepartureDate" id="DepartureDate" value="" placeholder="Loading.... please wait" readonly>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Click Here!">
</form>
```

The two date inputs use Jquery UI to provide a selectable calendar.

In the second page (book1.php) I use

```
if(empty($hid) {
```

to send me an email of the form has failed. This tells me the user-agent.

Generally it seems to be iPhones and iPads that are usually failing, though most others have done it at some time. I estimate it's happening in 2-5% of occasions when someone tries to use the form. What could be causing this random failure?

Comment: maybe someone is entering a incorrect date into the datepicker? I know that when the date picker recognizes that the date is not valid it will not accept its value in the code behind and will send a null which needs to be checked for in order to validate the form.

Comment: I thought you might be on to something there imBlue but I can't replicate it on my iPad. The only way of inputting the date is via the calendar and after that the "readonly" in the <input> tag prevents the keyboard appearing, so it's not possible to alter the date to something invalid. Similarly with a PC or Mac, you can't actually type in a date. Pity! I thought you might be my saviour.

Comment: can you console.log what is being sent just before the page redirect and after?

Comment: I've never used console.log so I'm flying a bit blind here, but doesn't the function just display info in the user's console? I have never been able to replicate the problem myself. I just know that occasional website users encounter the problem.
Meanwhile I tried deleting the "readonly" so that I could deliberately put in a wrongly formatted date. Every time the date defaulted to 1 Jan 1970, but apart from that everything worked correctly and normally.

Comment: can you give us a full page example on code pen or something? I will try to replicate it

Comment: I think the easiest thing is to quote an example page, and then you can see everything apart from the PHP (which I don't think is affecting anything). Try https://www.littlehotels.co.uk/spain/morvedra.php. Go to the "Book This Hotel" panel, put some dates in and hit "Click Here". If you get to the first stage of the booking process, it has worked as it should. If you get a page starting "Oh dear!", you've encountered the problem I'm trying to fix. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well the date seems to be alright, I was able to recreate the "Oh Dear!" issue only when I copy pasted the booking link from the new tab to another new tab. Maybe some of the users copied the link to another tab and thats why you are having an issue? How are you sending the dates to the new book1.php page?

Comment: That's very interesting, imBlue. Now you've shown me, I can create the problem that way too. It's a bit hard to see why anyone would want to do that. Possibly they reach book1.php and think they'll look at another hotel before going any further. So they copy the url, then  come back a couple of minutes later and try to paste it in. Why would iPad and iPhone users be more likely to do it than others? I can't see an answer to that, but perhaps there's something about using a touch screen that steers people that way.

Comment: I currently use POST method to pass information to book1.php. I suppose I could use GET, so that copying the url would contain all the necessary information to continue. Generally I've always preferred POST because it looks neater, but I'll read up to see if there are any dangers I haven't thought of.

Comment: your best bet would be a query string for now. Most hotel apps follow this practice of selecting a hotel and then opening a new window with a query string in the url that you can use. Its worth a shot to test it out and see if your Ipad users are having the same issue or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178456/discussion-between-trapezeartist-and-imblue).

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the failures were caused by users copying the url of book1.php and then pasting it into a fresh browser tab. As the data was being passed by POST method, the data was lost. I am now using GET method so the data is a part of the url, and there have been no failures since.

Comment: glad we got it figured out!